# ASP.NET Core best way to write modal Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have PartialView _CompanyTable:

```
<table class="table" id="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Company", new { id = item.Id })'>Edit</a>
                    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Company", new { id = item.Id })'>Dekete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

index page:

```
<div id="companyTable">
    <partial name="_CompanyTable" model="@Model" />
</div>
```

and Edit page:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Company" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I make Edit modal popup form for index(_CompanyTable)? I don't need to redirect from index to edit page, so I'm trying to do modal form the first time.

Comment: Could you clarify the question. It seems to me you are asking more about frontend than c# here.

Comment: A modal is rendered by the client, so you will need to involve client scripting at some point. And then it depends on how you want to approach that from JavaScript what you would need to do on the server.

Comment: In your view just add a hidden Bootstrap modal with all the stuff your want to show. Then show the modal with one line javascript on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery and AJAX technologies for this to happen.

Let's change your '_CompanyTable' partial view.

```
...
<table class="table" id="Table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>
                <a onclick="editCompany(`/Company/Edit?id=${item.Id}`)">Edit</a>
                <a onclick="deleteCompany(`/api/companies?id=${item.Id}`)">Dekete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
...
```

And, your Edit view.

```
...
<form onsubmit="return submitCompany(this)">
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
       <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
   </div>
</form>
...
```

In your '_CompanyTable' partial view, include the following JavaScript scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"> 
   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="company.js"></script>
```

Your company.js file will look like this.

```
    var popup;

    function editCompany(url) {
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');
        $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);
                popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizeable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 450,
                    title: 'Edit company',
                    close: function () {                         
                        popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    },
                });
            });
    }

    function deleteCompany(url) {
        swal({
            title: "Surely sure?",
            text: "Are you fully sure to delete?",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true
        }).then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: url,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            toastr.success(data.message);
                        }
                        else {
                            toastr.error(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

function submitCompany(form) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    var comp = $(form).serializeJSON();
    comp = JSON.stringify(comp);
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/companies/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: comp,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    toastr.success(data.message);
                    popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Cannot post data!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Change your CompanyController as follows.

```
 private readonly ICompanyRepository repository;

 public OrganizationController(ICompanyRepository repository)
 {
     this.repository = repository;
 }

 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
            Company = await repository.FindCompanyById(id);

        if (Company == null)
            Company = new Company();

        return PartialView(Company);
    }
```

Also, don't forget to add new API controller named CompaniesController in your project.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/companies")]
[ApiController]
public class OrganizationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICompanyRepository repository;

    public OrganizationsController(ICompanyRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Company>> Post(Company company)
    {
        if (company.Id > 0)
        {
            await repository.UpdateCompany(company);
        }
        else
        {
            await repository.AddCompany(organization);
        }

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Company information saved"});
    }

    
    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Company>> Delete(int id)
    {
        var company = await repository.FindCompanyById(id);

        if (company == null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Cannot delete this company" 
              });
        }
        await repository.DeleteCompany(company);

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Successfully deleted the 
         company");
    }
}
```

Add the following ICompanyRepository and CompanyRepository in your project.

```
public interface ICompanyRepository
{
    Task AddCompany(Company company);
    Task UpdateCompany(Company company);
    Task<Company> FindCompanyById(int? id);
    Task DeleteCompany(Company company);
}

public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository
{
    private readonly TaskManagerDbContext context;

    public OrganizationRepository(TaskManagerDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task AddCompany(Company company)
    {
        context.Companies.Add(company);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task DeleteCompany(Company company)
    {
        context.Companies.Remove(company);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Company> FindOrganizationById(int? id)
    {
        return await context.Companies.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task UpdateCompany(Company company)
    {
        var _company= context.Companies.Attach(company);
        _company.State = EntityState.Modified;
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

}

Last but not least, don't forget to register your repositories in the Startup.cs file.

```
services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
```

Hope, this answers to your question.